# Initialising 2d array using 1 d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Use of **2d array initialisation is forbidden** and  I am getting this error -

I am instructed to use main() as it is  and i can only edit other two functions .

```
source.cpp(81): error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'Array' used
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

Code:

```
int main(){
    int **Array;
    Array = getArray2D(10, 10, Array);
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        Array[i][j] = 4;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<10; j++){
            cout << Array[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}



int* getArray1D(int n, int *A)
{
    A = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        A[i] = 0;
    return A;
}
int** getArray2D(int m, int n, int** A)
{
    // m array of integers
    A = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        // create a 1d array on each element of a A
        A[i] = getArray1D(n, A[i]);

    }
    return A;
}
```

How can i correct this ?

Comment: the error is self-explanatory - you Array in the first line isn't initialised. Use only `getArray2D(10,10,Array)`. You may have problems with your pointer/variable type declaration

Comment: I am instructed to use main() as it is  and i can only edit other two functions .

Comment: Then whoever instructed you doesn't have a good understanding of C++.

Comment: This is the worst way to create a 2d array.

Comment: Its just a question to play with pointers and arrays , optimisation and overhead is tottaly ignored .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't initialize the `Array` to NULL and then you use it.

So change this:

```
int **Array;
Array = getArray2D(10, 10, Array);
```

to this:

```
int **Array = NULL;
Array = getArray2D(10, 10, Array);
```

What you get is actually a warning, not an error, that looks like this:

```
warning: ‘Array’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

---

Don't forget to de allocate your memory later!

Comment: This will remove the error message, but it isn't the correct fix. That parameter should not exist at all as the function doesn't use it.

Comment: The function uses the array @interjay. It could not use it and do it like this http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/, but in the OP's code it is used inside the function.

Comment: No, it isn't used inside the function. The function overwrites the value that was passed in without using the original value.

Comment: I am instructed to use main() as it is .

Comment: Yes I agree @interjay. Jimmy yes I saw your comment under the question. So, with the suggest from my answer you overpass the problem you had?

Comment: I am instructed to not modify the code written in main() as per problem specs @G.Samaras

Comment: @jimmy since this is for some homework, I would do this (I am a student too). I would modify just this line and write a comment explaining why I did this (because I get the warning that is treated as an error in your case) and could not compile the program. It will not make any bad influence of your rest of your code, believe me. The answer provides information on why you got this error and how to fix it, but I can't find a way to fix it without modifying main, so I strongly suggest you do what I mentioned above in this comment.

Comment: Oh OK, I just assumed that because you said that you are instructed not to modify main, sorry @jimmy.